# Проблема с реализацией выпадающего списка

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, openapi

Как сделать выпадающий список в `Swagger` документации в `laravel`?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить выпадающий список в `@OA\Parameter`, как я понял, нужно использовать `enum`, но от недостатка опыта вообще не соображу как его туда добавить..
Пробовал через `@OA\Schema`, но тоже ничего не вышло:

```
/**
 * @OA\Get (path="/event",
 *     tags={"Events"},
 *     operationId="getEvents",
 *     summary="get all events from Montevent",
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="url",
 *         in="query",
 *
 *         required=true,
 *         style="form"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="Successful operation",
 *          @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/EventResource")
 *       ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=401,
 *          description="Permission denied",
 *       )
 *  )
 */
```

Comment: Смотрите [англоязычный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917780/openapi-for-php-doesnt-render-enum-values-correctly) на этот вопрос.

Comment: Огромное вам Спасибо!